# Can I ssh to my board directly?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a robot that uses nano-pi board(something like raspberry). my robot is somewhere that there is no LAN network. So, can I use the LAN cable directly from the board(robot) to my laptop(Ubuntu 16.04 is the OS of both laptop/robot)?

Comment: (1) You might want to reword your question title to better reflect and align with the question that you are asking. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Have you tried searching [SU]? I searched for “network computers directly” and found [Transfer files directly between computers over Ethernet cable?](/q/510508/150988), [File transfer between Linux PC and Windows PC through Ethernet cable](/q/1119374/150988), [Connect 2 PCs directly with a cable](/q/594842/150988), [Two Vista machines are connected directly with a network cable](/q/59385/150988), [Direct network cable connection](/q/71922/150988) and [Direct cable connection of two notebooks](/q/367262/150988). Are any of them helpful to you?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. Two options:

1. In NetworkManager on the laptop create a new Ethernet connection and choose "Shared to other computers" as the method on both the IPv4 and IPv6 Settings tabs. The board will then use the laptop as a DHCP server.
2. In NetworkManager on both systems create a new Ethernet connection and choose "Link-local Only" on both tabs. This will give the network adapters automatically-generated IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

In both cases you should have Avahi running on the board so that you can connect to it using its Zeroconf address.

Note that doing this should be considered **insecure** on both systems (although not catastrophically so), and the rest of the network, firewall, and service settings should reflect this.

Comment: Thank you! But it means I should connect my robot to a network(like before) and install the `Avahi` then I can connect it directly as you said above?

Comment: You'll need to have Avahi installed, but you don't need a network to connect the two systems together.

Comment: My robot has no monitor and keyboard and I use `ssh` to programming it

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't run, say, `nm-connection-editor` over ssh?

Comment: I didn't try it yet, my robot is in an exhibition at now, and I am at home. I wanted to know if I can take my laptop there and try to upgrade it's program. I searched now inside my laptop and found that the `Avahi` is pre installed on my laptop, I hope it's installed on my robot by default too.

Comment: I used your first method and it says connection stablished but I don't know what ip should I use to connect to my board? in `ssh root@ip adress of my board` command

Comment: If Avahi is running on the board then you should be able to use *hostname*.local. If not then you'll have to try each possible address on the interface.

Comment: I also have Angry IP scanner and it finds `127.0.0.1` when I don't enter any IP range, also in wired connection it shows this ip but I cant connect with `ssh` command

Comment: That's the loopback address. That's not what you're looking for.

Comment: So how should I find the IP? Should I use shh command?

Comment: You can try pinging the broadcast address and see what responds.

Comment: ping 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Sorry am new in networking...may you explain more